# ¿Cómo calcular la diferencia en segundos entre una fila y la anterior?

Tags: mysql

llevo dias tratando de hacer un query que me cuente la cantidad de segundos entre una actividad y otra, en un log.

Tengo una tabla de log con historia y tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
id_registro | id_folio  | usuario  | tipo    |  fechahora          |
1           |  1000     | ftovar   |  SEND   | 2018-04-23 09:02:49 |
2           |  1000     | mgamboa  |  APPROVE| 2018-04-23 10:20:10 |
3           |  1000     | dvillota |  APPROVE| 2018-04-27 11:20:10 |
4           |  1000     | carias   |  TAKE   | 2018-04-28 09:02:49 |
5           |  1000     | nvaldez  |  STEAL  | 2018-04-29 10:20:10 |
6           |  1000     | nvaldez  |  CLOSE  | 2018-04-30 11:20:10 |
7           |  2000     | ftovar   |  SEND   | 2018-04-23 09:02:49 |
8           |  2000     | mgamboa  |  APPROVE| 2018-04-25 10:20:10 |
9           |  2000     | dvillota |  APPROVE| 2018-04-27 11:20:10 |
10          |  2000     | mgramkl  |  APPROVE| 2018-04-25 10:20:10 |
11          |  2000     | dtrelota |  APPROVE| 2018-04-27 11:20:10 |
...
```

Quisiera poder generar una tabla así, con el tiempo en segundos que toma entre el status anterior y ese:

```
folio  | user     | timeinseconds  |  type    |
1000   | mgamboa  |   0            |  APPROVE |
1000   | mgamboa  |   4641         |  APPROVE |
1000   | dvillota |   349200       |  APPROVE |
1000   | carias   |   78159        |  TAKE    |
...
```

la verdad estoy frustrado, si alguien lo a solucionado me podrían dar algo de luz, o algún método, no tiene que ser la solución completa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un interesante problema y se puede encarar de varias formas. Hay dos dificultades:

- Necesitamos obtener la fila anterior de la actual
- Hay que considerar lo anterior en función a los grupos de `folio`

En primer lugar creamos un conjunto de datos reproducible:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Historia (
    id_registro       INT,
    id_folio          INT,
    usuario           VARCHAR(50),
    tipo              VARCHAR(50),
    fechahora         DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO Historia (id_registro,id_folio,usuario,tipo,fechahora)
SELECT 1 , 1000, 'ftovar',   'SEND',    '2018-04-23 09:02:49' UNION
SELECT 2 , 1000, 'mgamboa',  'APPROVE', '2018-04-23 10:20:10' UNION
SELECT 3 , 1000, 'dvillota', 'APPROVE', '2018-04-27 11:20:10' UNION
SELECT 4 , 1000, 'carias',   'TAKE',    '2018-04-28 09:02:49' UNION
SELECT 5 , 1000, 'nvaldez',  'STEAL',   '2018-04-29 10:20:10' UNION
SELECT 6 , 1000, 'nvaldez',  'CLOSE',   '2018-04-30 11:20:10' UNION
SELECT 7 , 2000, 'ftovar',   'SEND',    '2018-04-23 09:02:49' UNION
SELECT 8 , 2000, 'mgamboa',  'APPROVE', '2018-04-25 10:20:10' UNION
SELECT 9 , 2000, 'dvillota', 'APPROVE', '2018-04-27 11:20:10' UNION
SELECT 10, 2000, 'mgramkl',  'APPROVE', '2018-04-25 10:20:10' UNION
SELECT 11, 2000, 'dtrelota', 'APPROVE', '2018-04-27 11:20:10';
```

La solución que propongo, se basa en generar un numerador para cada fila ordenado por `fechahora` y particionado (reinicializado) por cada `folio` distinto, esta consulta la persistiremos en una tabla temporal ya que es necesario acceder de forma recursiva a la misma y hacerlo así es más económico de escribir.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Historia_Temp (
    id_registro       INT,
    id_folio          INT,
    usuario           VARCHAR(50),
    tipo              VARCHAR(50),
    fechahora         DATETIME,
    nr                INT,
    id_folio_change   INT
) \\

INSERT INTO Historia_Temp (id_registro,id_folio,usuario,tipo,fechahora,nr,id_folio_change)
SELECT  H.id_registro,
        H.id_folio,
        H.usuario,
        H.tipo,
        H.fechahora,
        CASE WHEN @id_folio_ant <> H.id_folio THEN @rownum := 1 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 END AS nr,
        CASE WHEN @id_folio_ant <> H.id_folio THEN @id_folio_ant := H.id_folio END AS id_folio_change
    FROM Historia H,
    (SELECT @rownum := 0, @id_folio_ant :=-1) r               
    ORDER BY H.id_folio, H.fechahora
```

Ahora `Historia_Temp` es nuestra temporal que debiera ser idéntica a nuestra tabla original, solo con un dato muy importantye que es el numerador que mencionábamos. Y ahora si podremos consultar cada fila, relacionando esta con la fila inmediata anterior para poder obtener la diferencia:

```
SELECT T1.id_registro,
       T1.id_folio,
       T1.usuario,
       T1.tipo,
       T1.fechahora,
       T2.fechahora AS 'FechaAnterior',
       IFNULL(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(T1.fechahora) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(T2.fechahora),0) as 'DiffSegundos'
       FROM Historia_Temp T1
       LEFT JOIN Historia_Temp T2
            ON T2.nr = T1.nr - 1
            AND T1.id_folio = T2.id_folio
       ORDER BY T1.id_folio, T1.nr
```

Salida:

```
╔════╦═════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═════════╦═════════════════════╦══════════════╗
║ #  ║ id_registro ║ id_folio ║ usuario  ║ tipo    ║ fechahora           ║ DiffSegundos ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 1  ║ 1           ║ 1000     ║ ftovar   ║ SEND    ║ 23.04.2018 09:02:49 ║ 0            ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 2  ║ 2           ║ 1000     ║ mgamboa  ║ APPROVE ║ 23.04.2018 10:20:10 ║ 4641         ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 3  ║ 3           ║ 1000     ║ dvillota ║ APPROVE ║ 27.04.2018 11:20:10 ║ 349200       ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 4  ║ 4           ║ 1000     ║ carias   ║ TAKE    ║ 28.04.2018 09:02:49 ║ 78159        ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 5  ║ 5           ║ 1000     ║ nvaldez  ║ STEAL   ║ 29.04.2018 10:20:10 ║ 91041        ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 6  ║ 6           ║ 1000     ║ nvaldez  ║ CLOSE   ║ 30.04.2018 11:20:10 ║ 90000        ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 7  ║ 7           ║ 2000     ║ ftovar   ║ SEND    ║ 23.04.2018 09:02:49 ║ 0            ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 8  ║ 8           ║ 2000     ║ mgamboa  ║ APPROVE ║ 25.04.2018 10:20:10 ║ 177441       ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 9  ║ 10          ║ 2000     ║ mgramkl  ║ APPROVE ║ 25.04.2018 10:20:10 ║ 0            ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 10 ║ 9           ║ 2000     ║ dvillota ║ APPROVE ║ 27.04.2018 11:20:10 ║ 176400       ║
╠════╬═════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 11 ║ 11          ║ 2000     ║ dtrelota ║ APPROVE ║ 27.04.2018 11:20:10 ║ 0            ║
╚════╩═════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comentrarios

- Como puedes ver, hacemos un `LEFT JOIN` de la tabla con si misma, solo que una fila desfazada `T2.nr = T1.nr - 1`
- Con `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` obtenemos los segundos de cualquier fecha/hora desde las 00 hs del 1/1//1970, la diferencia entre los dos `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` son los segundos entre un a y otra fecha/hora
- Es una solución relativamente ANSI SQL, es probable que exista una mecánica más óptima o directa en mysql.